# Unable to get user attributes using profile/openid scopes from AWS Cognito

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

I am using Cognito and ADFS integration for one of my web app. After the integration, I get the tokens correctly from Cognito. However, when I try to retrieve user's attributes using `Auth.userAttributes()`, I get a 400 error code with following error:

> {__type: "NotAuthorizedException", message: "Access Token does not
> have required scopes"} message: "Access Token does not have required
> scopes"
> __type: "NotAuthorizedException"

I decoded the received access token on jwt.io and it correctly has the openid and profile scopes

> "scope": "openid profile email"

As per the Auth standards, I expect that these scopes should be enough to READ a basic user profile. Is this not a correct expectation ?

P.S: I tried asking for a token with `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope and this seems to make the user attribute call without error. However, why is this required. I don't want to expose to the user any access token to modify any information

Answer (score 2):

In my own experience with Cognito access tokens, you are unable to add custom claims to them. This has some good and bad points:

**Pros**

- Tokens used by web and mobile apps do not reveal sensitive data

**Cons**

- Tokens alone do not enable APIs to do their authorization properly

You can get the details you need by sending the access token to the User Info endpoint though. It is possible to do this when an access token is first received, then cache custom claims for future requests with the same access token:

- [Getting user info claims](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts#L71)
- [Creating a custom claims principal](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts#L30)

You can run the above code sample by following its README. The main point of the API security code is to form a useful claims principal that the API can use for its business authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using aws amplify for this task.

As you are using federated sign in to authenticate user, you will get user attributes in the following way:

```js
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
const {yourAttributeName} = user.signInUserSession.idToken.payload;
```

Though you are not using cognito user pool user for this task, but you can access their user attributes like the following way:

```js
const {yourAttributeName} = (await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()).attributes;
```

If the above solution doesn't work, Make sure your Scopes are properly setup in your userpool app and Identify Provider have a proper attribute mapping setup and have read-write permission on the attributes that you are expecting to read.

Comment: I am using exactly the way you have mentioned. My question however is that, this approach only works when your access token contain the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin`. I am expecting the same to work with just the `openid ` scope

Comment: last time I tried to access user attribute with only `openid` scope and it didn't work, but it worked when there is another `profile` scope too because user attributes can be accessed with `profile` scope. But if you provide `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` it will work but with a huge security risk. I prefer you to use `profile` scope which should work, but make sure you have a proper setting in the cognito userpool as mentioned in the answer.  **idToken will have userAttributes including custom attributes**

Comment: I would expect that to happen, but I tried with profile and it didn't work. It works only with `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin`

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari did you find the answer , i have same issue

Comment: @csf No I didn't get any solution to this. If you read my P.S note at the end of the question. You will find an alternative way to achieve this